# Delimit/text to columns .CSV file before extracting data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that goes through .xlsx , .xls, and .csv files(many files). But the .csv file data are usually all in column A separated by "|". How can I delimit these files first before looping through them and pulling an extract? It can be complicated because sometimes not only Col A has data but Col B may have a few rows.

EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
          Sub ColumnHeaders()
    'includes filling down
    'Skips unreadable files

        Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean
        Dim wsReport As Excel.Worksheet
        Set wsReport = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'Whatever sheet you want to write to
        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = 1


         ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculation
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        End With


    'get user input for files to search
    Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
    If errCheck Then
       Exit Sub
    End If
    '''
    For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary


    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0    ' or your custom error handler

    If wb Is Nothing Then
    wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = fileNames(Key)

    Else
        Debug.Print "Successfully loaded " & fileNames(Key)
        wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible
        '--------------------DATA Extraction ----------------------------------------

Dim iIndex As Integer
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lOutputCol As Long


'Loop through the worksheets in the current workbook.
For iIndex = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count

    'Set the current worksheet
    Set ws = Application.Worksheets(iIndex)

    'List out the workbook and worksheet names
    wsReport.Range("A" & lRow).Value = wb.Name
    wsReport.Range("B" & lRow).Value = ws.Name

    'Start a counter of the columns that we are writing to
    lOutputCol = 3

    'Loop through the columns.
    For lCol = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        'Write the header
        wsReport.Range(Col_Letter(lOutputCol) & lRow).Value = ws.Range(Col_Letter(lCol) & "1").Value

        'Increment our column counters.
        lOutputCol = lOutputCol + 1
    Next lCol

    'Increment the row we are writing to
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next iIndex

'-----------------------Data Extraction END-------------------------------------

wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save
Set wb = Nothing 'release the object
End If

Next 'End of the fileNames loop
Set fileNames = Nothing


' Reset system settings
With Application
   .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Visible = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches.

APPROACH #1

Your code first opens the file *as text*, then prepends (inserts as the first line) to the file this:

```
sep=|
```

Next, your code then opens as CSV in Excel. If your text qualifiers are normal quotes, this will work surprisingly well.

I know that prepending is a little tricky in VBA. If the file is not too big, then you would create a new file with that first line followed by the rest of the original file (e.g. http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=163510).

The advantage of this approach is that your VBA doesn't need to do text-to-columns, etc.

APPROACH #2
The VBA loops through all rows and columns to clean up first before performing text-to-columns. As you said, if the delimiter is non-standard, you often end up with values in column B or C or even more so you need "clean up" first by putting them all back into column A.

I used to run my own little macro to do this cleaning up for exactly this reason i.e. "|" as a delimiter.

Later, I discovered that I could insert "sep=|" (e.g. using Notepad++) before opening in Excel.

I wrote a short article on both approaches and offered my code here: https://wildwoollytech.wordpress.com/2015/12/11/combine-excel-cells-into-one/

Comment: Hi Stifin, having some trouble. I added my code. Still cleaning up some of the stuff I dont need but if you have time could you take a look into how I could use your approach #2/

Comment: @Jonathan, did you work it out, yet? From what I can see in your code, you need _three_ nested loops. You're using two (i.e. you're not looping through the rows). These are the three you need: 1) Loop through the __worksheets__ in the current workbook; 2) Loop through the __rows__ in the current worksheet (you're missing this); 3) Loop through the __columns__ in the current row